# Pass file to another project in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I'm trying to create simple app for editing .xml files. I have created another project within one solution to which I'm trying to pass file, where I would like to edit and save it. But is that possible? I have tried to import `System.web` and then request `HttpPostedFile` as parameter of one function, but VS do not recognize such type there. What am I doing wrong?

[image: HttpPostedFile not recognized despite System.Web imported]

Alternatively, what is better way to pass file from one project to another?

Comment: A "using" directive is not the same as a "reference" to the System.Web assembly - which did you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to realize passing data between different classes.

One way is to pass it with a `Stream`, as `System.File.Open` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.open(v=vs.110).aspx)) already gives back a `FileStream`. With streams you need to be careful with the handling of opening, closing, reading etc (see [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)).

Another way is by simply passing the path of the file as a string and open it elsewhere. But as you are trying to use a `HttpPostedFile`-object, I guess you're working on a project running on 2 different machines.

You should read into streaming data, and with streaming it's irrelevant if you got the data from a file, a request or even another stream.

Edit: It seems your main first problem here was that the class `HttpPostedFile` was in a assembly you didnt referenced before. You can get tips for situations like these by pressing `Ctrl` + `.`. VS suggests you things like creating a class for unknown objects or, if it's a common known object, adding references.